# Representing a 1D function as a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, polar-coordinates

I made a program to solve the Lane-Emden equation, which gives the density of a star as a function of its radius r. I'm trying to plot this 1D function in a 2D plane, in polar coordinates, but where the function doesn't depend of the angular coordinate.

Comment: you forgot to ask a question, what is your problem? be clear and post your code even if doesn't work. post it as text, not as an image.

Comment: Density as a function of radius sounds like 2 dimensions...

Comment: The cartesian plane is 2D as well. How exactly are polar coordinates used?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.